# Set Transaction Isolation Level Disappears From table-valued function T-SQL In Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table-valued function to which I added:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
```

and executed an alter function. However, when I open up said TVF in Management Studio again, the above line does not appear, as it has been removed. Is this by design or am I doing something wrong?

Here is the table-valued function I'm trying to save with the above isolation level.

```
USE [playerspace]
GO

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[udf_get_games_by_date_league_id_group_id]    Script Date: 3/21/2015 8:59:32 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_get_games_by_date_league_id_group_id] 
    (@league_id int, @group_id int,
     @division_id int, @tournament_division_id int,
     @season_id int, @date1 datetime, @date2 datetime)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
   RETURN 
       WITH events_by_date_CTE (event_type, str_event_address, str_event_title, str_event_description, str_event_location, f_score_set_by, int_game_status, f_home_team_id, f_group_id, f_visitor_team_id, f_season_id, f_league_id, f_member_id, p_event_id, f_division_id, int_visitor_team_score, int_home_team_score, f_zipcode_id, dte_event_start, dte_event_end, gamedaypart, gameday, tme_event_start, f_play_location_id, f_league_schedule_id, f_tournament_division_id, f_play_location_time_slot_id, str_location_name, str_event_address_linked, str_cityname_linked, str_zipcode_linked, str_statecode_linked, str_preferredcityname, str_cityname, str_zipcode, str_statename, str_statecode, visitorgroupurl, str_league_name, str_league_url, str_group_url, int_organization_type, homegroupurl, visitorteamname, hometeamname, str_group_name,int_lon,int_lat,str_division,str_tournament_division,str_season,admin_list,int_timeslot_length_in_minutes,zonename,zoneabbrev,zonegmtoffset,zonedst,zonename_linked,zoneabbrev_linked,zonegmtoffset_linked,zonedst_linked)
AS
-- Define the CTE query.
(
    select event_type,str_event_address,str_event_title,str_event_description,str_event_location,f_score_set_by,int_game_status,f_home_team_id,f_group_id,f_visitor_team_id,f_season_id,f_league_id,f_member_id,p_event_id,f_division_id,int_visitor_team_score,int_home_team_score,f_zipcode_id,dte_event_start,dte_event_end,gamedaypart,gameday,tme_event_start,f_play_location_id,f_league_schedule_id,f_tournament_division_id,f_play_location_time_slot_id,str_location_name,str_event_address_linked,str_cityname_linked,str_zipcode_linked,str_statecode_linked,str_preferredcityname,str_cityname,str_zipcode,str_statename,str_statecode,visitorgroupurl,str_league_name,str_league_url,str_group_url,int_organization_type,homegroupurl,visitorteamname,hometeamname,str_group_name,int_lon,int_lat,str_division,str_tournament_division,str_season,admin_list,int_timeslot_length_in_minutes,zonename,zoneabbrev,zonegmtoffset,zonedst,zonename_linked,zoneabbrev_linked,zonegmtoffset_linked,zonedst_linked
    from udf_get_events_by_date_group_id_league_id(@league_id,@group_id,@division_id,@tournament_division_id,@season_id,@date1,@date2)
)
(
    select * from events_by_date_CTE as games_query
    where 1=1
)
GO
```

Comment: Did you add this statement **inside** the stored procedure - or outside? Was this **inside** the `CREATE PROCEDURE ....` block? Otherwise, it was just a statement to SQL Server and isn't actually part of the procedure, so therefore it would be discarded...

Comment: I'm sorry i meant table valued function not SPROC.

Comment: Your `SET TRANSACTION ....` statement is **outside** the function definition, and therefore it is **NOT** part of the function and will **NOT** be stored with the function. Works as designed.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but why read uncommitted? Have you explored read committed snapshot to solve what I can only assume are perceived concurrency problems?

Comment: I just want to reduce deadlocks by doing the dirtiest possible read on some of these queries I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SET operator in this case is not part of UDF.
Also you can not use SET operators in UDF's

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191320.aspx

> 1. User-defined functions cannot be used to perform actions that modify
>    the database state.
> 2. User-defined functions cannot contain an OUTPUT
>    INTO clause that has a table as its target.
> 3. User-defined functions can
>    not return multiple result sets. Use a stored procedure if you need to
>    return multiple result sets.
> 4. Error handling is restricted in a
>    user-defined function.
> 5. A UDF does not support TRY…CATCH, @ERROR or
>    RAISERROR.
> 6. User-defined functions cannot call a stored procedure, but
>    can call an extended stored procedure.
> 7. User-defined functions cannot
>    make use of dynamic SQL or temp tables. Table variables are allowed.
> 8. SET statements are not allowed in a user-defined function.
> 9. The FOR XML
>    clause is not allowed

Look at bullet 8.

Comment: Can I set the transaction isolation level when doing a query of the UDF?
For eg: 
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted
select * from udf

Comment: Of course you can do if set statement will be valid in that particular situation.

Answer (score 1):

Very strange but lets do a test....

**Procedure Definition**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test_Procs
AS
BEGIN
 SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

   SELECT 'Test_Procs executed'
END
```

**Check Procedure Definition**

```
exec sp_helptext 'Test_Procs'
```

**Procedure Definition**

```
It returns exactly the same definition as above.
```

Comment: From `I added ... and executed` I interpret it to mean `SET TRANSACTION ... GO ... ALTER SPROC`. It would apply to the session, it's not text in the stored procedure. I think OP is confusing the `SET ANSI NULLS ...` preamble that SSMS adds to the `Script To ... Create` scripts.

Comment: Sorry I meant table-valued function, not sproc